# Error with Icon class that sows up only on web not with aplet-viewer

Tags: java, image, swing, applet

I have a class that loads a array of icons, my applet uses 2 such arrays, one for images and one for their thumbnails.
I have a animation thread that rotates a set of 6 thumbnails through the array of thumbnails as well as a slider that allows for scrolling through the thumbnails.

When i use applet-viewer the program works fine but if i package the applet and view it on a browser OR if i upload the unpackaged applet onto a website the thumbnails, but NOT the images that use the same class to load does not show up on the screen and the functionality that comes with the thumbnails becomes laggy.

I cant promise that the site wont change but you can try to see the bugs yourself at http://tokweweb.uphero.com/

here is the code for the class that is giving me the problem:

Thank you

```
    public class IconArray {
    private ImageIcon[] Icons;
    private int Count;
    private String Filepath;

    IconArray(String filepath, int count){
        Count = count;
        Icons = new ImageIcon[Count];
        Filepath = filepath;
    }

    IconArray(String filepath, int count, boolean Autoload){
        Count = count;
        Icons = new ImageIcon[Count];
        Filepath = filepath;
        if(Autoload){
            for(int i = 0; i<Count; i++){
                Icons[i] = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(Filepath+i+".jpg"));
            }
        }
    }

    public Icon GetIcon(final int i) throws InterruptedException{
        if(Icons[i]!=null){
          return Icons[i];
          }else{
            Integer temp = new Integer(i);
            Icons[i] = new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(Filepath+temp.toString()+".jpg"));
            return Icons[i];
        }    
    }

    public int GetCount(){
        return Count;
    }

}
```

Comment: Consider cutting your code progressively in an effort to try to isolate the problem. This way either you'll find the error or you'll end up with a very small compilable and runnable program that demonstrates your problem which you can post here.

Comment: your applet throws class version exception?..

Comment: @DanglingPiyush: I though so too, at first; it looks like a request for the class file is returning `404`.

Comment: By the look of it, that is definitely ***not*** something that should be done inside an applet.  The user cannot copy/paste text from the info., and it is not compatible with search engines at all.

Answer (score 3):

Your applet appears to consist of a single class file. You probably want to bundle the images with your class in a JAR file, as shown in [*Using Images in a Swing Applet*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/applet.html#images).

Comment: I have isolated the problem as requested, i have also found some posts on this site that descibes something similar 
http://www.coderanch.com/t/511439/java/java/load-file-getResource
but in that case the nullpointer exeption happens immediately
there is no difference in runtime behaviour when pakaging the applet and viewing in a browser or using applet viewer.
Also the images are pakaged with the code at this stage
here is my code:

Comment: It looks like `filepath` may shadow `Filepath`; the first thing to check would be the calculated path versus the actual path, e.g. `jar tf your.jar`.

Comment: I have found the error, the IconArray class expects the images to have .jpg as the file ending while my thumbnails ended as .JPG, as a newcomer to Java and web programming in general I did not know that that would make a difference, and I could not see the difference in windows explorer as it hides known file extensions by default, thank you all for your comments, it helped focus my thoughts and pointed me in directions I might not have thought of myself